# mostrar solamente la hora y minutos de timestamp mysql

Tags: mysql, data

tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql que lo que me da son los datos en la ultimos 60min de realizada la consulta.

```
SELECT fecha_datos,ppm_datos FROM datos_device WHERE device_datos = :macnum AND fecha_datos >= now() - interval 60 minute;
```

La tabla de salida es la siguiente:

[image: Datos de la tabla]

Yo lo que ruiero que de la columna fecha solo muestre los minutos y la hora y el resto sacarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con `**DATE_FORMAT()**` puedes hacerlo

```
**DATE_FORMAT(fecha_datos, '%H:%i') AS hora**


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_datos, '%H:%i') AS hora, ppm_datos FROM datos_device WHERE device_datos = :macnum AND fecha_datos >= now() - interval 60 minute;
```

Referencia:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Muchas gracias había intentado usar el date_formate pero lo estaba usando mal por lo que se ve, con tu indicación anda perfecto.

Comment: @SantiagoIvanMallaviabarrena no hay de que, en la página oficial que puse como referencia puedes encontrar funciones muy útiles que te pueden servir para solucionar los problemas, igual puedes ir practicando en la página de hackerrank sobre estos temas, igual si estás utilizando PHP otra solución seria con la función **date()** así  `$hora = date("H:i", strtotime($fecha_datos));`

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya intentaste en tu base de datos en el tipo solo seleccionar TIME y dejando el TIMESTAMP intacto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]